# `expss` and `data.table` not playing well together

Tags: r, data.table, expss

I am working with the `expss` package to produce banner tables for survey data, but I keep getting an error that doesn't come up a lot on Google: `Error in data.table(cell_var, col_var, row_var) :   object '.R.listCopiesNamed' not found`.

I've created a reproducible example below. It's unclear to me if it's an error from `expss` or from `data.table`, or from the combination of the two. In any case there a way to override the need for `'.R.listCopiesNamed'`, or some other way to resolve the error?

I'm working in this environment:
`R version 3.4.4 (2018-03-15) -- "Someone to Lean On"
Copyright (C) 2018 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)`

Reproducible example:

```
# load packages
library(expss)
library(tidyverse)

# generate some data
set.seed(369)
age <- base::sample(c("18-24", "25-24", "35-44", "45-54", "55-64", "65+"), 
                    100, replace = TRUE)
sex <- base::sample(c("Male", "Female"), 
                    100, replace = TRUE)
likelihood <- base::sample(c("Much more likely", "Somewhat more likely", 
                             "Equally likely", "Somewhat less likely", 
                             "Much less likely"), 100, replace = TRUE)
importance <- base::sample(c("Extremely important", "Somewhat important", 
                             "Neutral", "Somewhat unimportant", 
                             "Extremely unimportant"), 100, replace = TRUE)
relevance <- base::sample(c("Extremely relevant", "Somewhat relevant", 
                            "Neutral", "Somewhat irrelevant", 
                            "Extremely irrelevant"), 100, replace = TRUE)
data <- data.frame(age, sex, likelihood, importance, relevance)

# make a simple banner table with significance testing
myTable <- data %>%
    tab_cells(likelihood, importance, relevance) %>%
    tab_cols(total(), age, sex) %>%
    tab_stat_cpct() %>%
    tab_last_sig_cpct() %>%
    tab_pivot()
```

At this point, I get the error:
`Error in data.table(cell_var, col_var, row_var) : 
  object '.R.listCopiesNamed' not found`

~*~*~*~*~*~*~

Edited to add traceback() and sessionInfo():

```
> traceback()
19: data.table(cell_var, col_var, row_var)
18: make_datatable_for_cro(cell_var = cell_var, col_var = col_var, 
        row_var = row_var, weight = weight, subgroup = subgroup)
17: elementary_cro(cell_var = each_cell_var, col_var = each_col_var, 
        row_var = each_row_var, weight = weight, subgroup = subgroup, 
        total_label = total_label, total_statistic = total_statistic, 
        total_row_position = total_row_position, stat_type = stat_type)
16: FUN(X[[i]], ...)
15: lapply(col_vars, function(each_col_var) {
        elementary_cro(cell_var = each_cell_var, col_var = each_col_var, 
            row_var = each_row_var, weight = weight, subgroup = subgroup, 
            total_label = total_label, total_statistic = total_statistic, 
            total_row_position = total_row_position, stat_type = stat_type)
    })
14: FUN(X[[i]], ...)
13: lapply(cell_vars, function(each_cell_var) {
        all_col_vars = lapply(col_vars, function(each_col_var) {
            elementary_cro(cell_var = each_cell_var, col_var = each_col_var, 
                row_var = each_row_var, weight = weight, subgroup = subgroup, 
                total_label = total_label, total_statistic = total_statistic, 
                total_row_position = total_row_position, stat_type = stat_type)
        })
        Reduce(merge, all_col_vars)
    })
12: FUN(X[[i]], ...)
11: lapply(row_vars, function(each_row_var) {
        res = lapply(cell_vars, function(each_cell_var) {
            all_col_vars = lapply(col_vars, function(each_col_var) {
                elementary_cro(cell_var = each_cell_var, col_var = each_col_var, 
                    row_var = each_row_var, weight = weight, subgroup = subgroup, 
                    total_label = total_label, total_statistic = total_statistic, 
                    total_row_position = total_row_position, stat_type = stat_type)
            })
            Reduce(merge, all_col_vars)
        })
        res = do.call(add_rows, res)
    })
10: multi_cro(cell_vars = cell_vars, col_vars = col_vars, row_vars = row_vars, 
        weight = weight, subgroup = subgroup, total_label = total_label, 
        total_statistic = total_statistic, total_row_position = total_row_position, 
        stat_type = "cpct")
9: cro_cpct(cell_vars = get_cells(data), col_vars = data[[COL_VAR]], 
       row_vars = data[[ROW_VAR]], weight = data[[WEIGHT]], subgroup = 
data[[SUBGROUP]], 
       total_label = total_label, total_statistic = total_statistic, 
       total_row_position = total_row_position)
8: tab_stat_cpct(.)
7: function_list[[i]](value)
6: freduce(value, `_function_list`)
5: `_fseq`(`_lhs`)
4: eval(quote(`_fseq`(`_lhs`)), env, env)
3: eval(quote(`_fseq`(`_lhs`)), env, env)
2: withVisible(eval(quote(`_fseq`(`_lhs`)), env, env))
1: data %>% tab_cells(likelihood, importance, relevance) %>% tab_cols(total(), 
       age, sex) %>% tab_stat_cpct() %>% tab_last_sig_cpct() %>% 
       tab_pivot()


> sessionInfo()
R version 3.4.4 (2018-03-15)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Sierra 10.12.6

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib

LAPACK: 
/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] en_CA.UTF-8/en_CA.UTF-8/en_CA.UTF-8/C/en_CA.UTF-8/en_CA.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] expss_0.8.6

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_0.12.17       matrixStats_0.53.1 digest_0.6.15      backports_1.1.2   
 [5] magrittr_1.5       stringi_1.1.6      data.table_1.11.4  rstudioapi_0.7    
 [9] checkmate_1.8.5    tools_3.4.4        stringr_1.3.0      foreign_0.8-69    
[13] htmlwidgets_1.2    yaml_2.1.17        compiler_3.4.4     htmltools_0.3.6   
[17] knitr_1.20         htmlTable_1.11.2
```

Comment: can you run traceback() after this error? and also include your package versions

Comment: It works for me. It's either some tidyverse collision on version like Michael said. What for are you loading tidyverse here anyway? You are not using it here at all.

Comment: @DavidArenburg I just ran the code without loading tidyverse, and got the same error. Regardless, I would have tidyverse loaded in the realworld, so if it's causing the interference then that's important to know. (But it appears as though tidyverse is not the cause of this error.)

Comment: @MichaelChirico I've added the traceback() and systemInfo() to the question. Updating my packages now, to see if that's the problem.

Comment: @MichaelChirico It was indeed the package version -- thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: happy to help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution: Update the `expss` package. Thanks to @MichaelChirico for the suggestion!