# error from data.table on shinyapps.io server but not locally

Tags: r, shiny, data.table, shinyapps, expss

I'm developing my first shiny app -- it is working great locally, but produces an error when I publish to shinyapps.io: `Error in data.table: object '.R.listCopiesNamed' not found`.

[I have encountered this error locally before, but the issue was resolved when I updated my packages.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51084894/expss-and-data-table-not-playing-well-together) Because the error was so easy to resolve locally, and because the error seems to depend on the version of the packages being used by the app, I suspect that there is something in my local environment that shinyapps.io is not recreating on the server -- but I don't know how to track down what is not being recreated in order to add it into my code.

Things I've tried (that all produce the same error):

- Updating all of my packages.
- [Backtracking to an older version](https://github.com/gdemin/expss/issues/7) of `data.table`.
- Explicitly telling the app to use the versions of the packages that were loaded locally.

Can any one shine some light onto what might be happening locally that isn't being reproduced on the shinyapps.io server? Thanks!

Reproducible example:

```
library(shiny)
library(data.table)
library(expss)
library(DT)
library(lubridate)
library(tidyverse)

# define UI for application
ui <- fixedPage(
# sidebar with dropdown menus for selecting year, month, and question
fixedRow(
    column(4,
           # dropdown menu for year
           selectInput(inputId = "myYear",
                       label = "Year",
                       choices = c("2018"), # update this list once per year
                       selected = "2018"),  # change this to current year
           # dropdown menu for month
           selectInput(inputId = "myMonth",
                       label = "Month",
                       choices = c(# "January" = 01, 
                           # "February" = 02, 
                           # "March" = 03, 
                           # "April" = 04, 
                           # "May" = 05,
                           # "June" = 06, 
                           # "July" = 07, 
                           # "August" = 08, 
                           "September" = "09", 
                           "October" = "10" #, 
                           # "November" = "11", 
                           # "December" = "12"
                       )),
           # dropdown menu for question
           selectInput(inputId = "myQuestion",
                       label = "Question",
                       choices = c("Q2_awareness", "Q3_association"))),

    # show a data table
    column(8, dataTableOutput("myBrandTable"))
)
)



# ------------------------------------------------------------------------ #
##### LOAD THE DATA FRAMES TO WORK WITH #####
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------ #

# create data
set.seed(123)
myBrandData <- data.frame(
brand = sample(c("Brand A", "Brand B", "Brand C", "Brand D", "Brand E", "Brand F", "Brand G"),
               100, replace = TRUE),
report_date = sample(c("Benchmark", "September 2018", "October 2018"),
                     100, replace = TRUE),
Q2_awareness = sample(c(0, 1), 100, replace = TRUE),
Q3_awareness = sample(c(0, 1), 100, replace = TRUE)
)

# relevel some factors so they show up in the desired order
myBrandData <- myBrandData %>%
mutate(report_date = fct_relevel(report_date,
                                 "Benchmark",
                                 "September 2018",
                                 "October 2018")) %>%
mutate_at(vars(starts_with("Q")), funs(as.numeric(.)))

# ------------------------------------------------------------------------ #
###### HELPER FUNCTIONS #####
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------ #

# a function from Gregory Demin for calculating stats on dichotomous multiple response variables
tab_stat_dich = function(data, total_label = NULL, total_statistic = "u_cases",
                     label = NULL){

if (missing(total_label) && !is.null(data[["total_label"]])) {
    total_label = data[["total_label"]]
}
if(is.null(total_label)){
    total_label = "#Total"
}

# calculate means
res = eval.parent(
    substitute(
        tab_stat_mean_sd_n(data,
                           weighted_valid_n = "w_cases" %in% total_statistic,
                           labels = c("|", "@@@@@", total_label),
                           label = label)
    )
)
curr_tab = res[["result"]][[length(res[["result"]])]]
# drop standard deviation
curr_tab = curr_tab[c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE), ]

# convert means to percent
curr_tab[c(TRUE, FALSE), -1] = curr_tab[c(TRUE, FALSE), -1] * 100
## clear row labels
curr_tab[[1]] = gsub("^(.+?)\\|(.+)$", "\\2", curr_tab[[1]], perl = TRUE )

res[["result"]][[length(res[["result"]])]] = curr_tab
res
}


# define server logic required to create the line graph & data table
server <- function(input, output) {
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------ #
##### MODIFY THE DATA FRAMES THAT GO INTO THE OUTPUTS ####
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------ #

myBrandTableData <- reactive({
    myBrandData %>%
        mutate(brand = fct_relevel(brand,
                                   "Brand A",
                                   "Brand B",
                                   "Brand C", 
                                   "Brand D", 
                                   "Brand E", 
                                   "Brand F", 
                                   "Brand G")) %>%
        select(report_date, Brand = brand, Variable = input$myQuestion)
})

# ------------------------------------------------------------------------ #
##### BUILD THE OUTPUTS #####
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------ #

# build the data table for brand comparisons
output$myBrandTable <- renderDataTable({
    # some note about the table
    as.datatable_widget(
        myBrandTableData() %>%
                tab_cells(Variable) %>%
                tab_cols(Brand) %>%
                tab_total_label("# Responses") %>%
                tab_stat_dich() %>%
                tab_last_sig_cpct() %>%
                tab_pivot()
    )
})
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

`sessionInfo()`:

```
R version 3.4.4 (2018-03-15)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Sierra 10.12.6

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] en_CA.UTF-8/en_CA.UTF-8/en_CA.UTF-8/C/en_CA.UTF-8/en_CA.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] bindrcpp_0.2.2    forcats_0.3.0     stringr_1.3.1     dplyr_0.7.7       purrr_0.2.5       readr_1.1.1      
 [7] tidyr_0.8.2       tibble_1.4.2      ggplot2_3.1.0     tidyverse_1.2.1   lubridate_1.7.4   DT_0.5           
[13] expss_0.8.7       data.table_1.11.8 shiny_1.2.0      

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] Rcpp_0.12.19       lattice_0.20-35    assertthat_0.2.0   digest_0.6.18      mime_0.6          
 [6] R6_2.3.0           cellranger_1.1.0   plyr_1.8.4         backports_1.1.2    httr_1.3.1        
[11] pillar_1.3.0       rlang_0.3.0.1      lazyeval_0.2.1     readxl_1.1.0       rstudioapi_0.8    
[16] checkmate_1.8.5    labeling_0.3       foreign_0.8-71     htmlwidgets_1.3    RCurl_1.95-4.11   
[21] munsell_0.5.0      broom_0.5.0        compiler_3.4.4     httpuv_1.4.5       modelr_0.1.2      
[26] pkgconfig_2.0.2    htmltools_0.3.6    tidyselect_0.2.5   htmlTable_1.12     matrixStats_0.54.0
[31] crayon_1.3.4       withr_2.1.2        later_0.7.5        bitops_1.0-6       grid_3.4.4        
[36] nlme_3.1-131.1     jsonlite_1.5       xtable_1.8-3       gtable_0.2.0       magrittr_1.5      
[41] scales_1.0.0       cli_1.0.1          stringi_1.2.4      promises_1.0.1     xml2_1.2.0        
[46] tools_3.4.4        RJSONIO_1.3-0      glue_1.3.0         hms_0.4.2          crosstalk_1.0.0   
[51] rsconnect_0.8.8    yaml_2.2.0         colorspace_1.3-2   rvest_0.3.2        knitr_1.20        
[56] bindr_0.1.1        haven_1.1.2
```

Lines from the logs file:

```
2018-11-07T15:12:29.128343+00:00 shinyapps[556963]: ✖ lubridate::intersect()   masks base::intersect()
2018-11-07T15:12:29.128348+00:00 shinyapps[556963]: ✖ dplyr::na_if()           masks expss::na_if()
2018-11-07T15:12:29.128349+00:00 shinyapps[556963]: ✖ tidyr::nest()            masks expss::nest()
2018-11-07T15:12:29.128349+00:00 shinyapps[556963]: ✖ lubridate::quarter()     masks data.table::quarter()
2018-11-07T15:12:29.128350+00:00 shinyapps[556963]: ✖ dplyr::recode()          masks expss::recode()
2018-11-07T15:12:29.128345+00:00 shinyapps[556963]: ✖ dplyr::lst()             masks tibble::lst(), expss::lst()
2018-11-07T15:12:29.128350+00:00 shinyapps[556963]: ✖ stringr::regex()         masks expss::regex()
2018-11-07T15:12:29.128346+00:00 shinyapps[556963]: ✖ lubridate::mday()        masks data.table::mday()
2018-11-07T15:12:29.128351+00:00 shinyapps[556963]: ✖ lubridate::second()      masks data.table::second()
2018-11-07T15:12:29.128346+00:00 shinyapps[556963]: ✖ lubridate::minute()      masks data.table::minute()
2018-11-07T15:12:29.128351+00:00 shinyapps[556963]: ✖ lubridate::setdiff()     masks base::setdiff()
2018-11-07T15:12:29.128347+00:00 shinyapps[556963]: ✖ purrr::modify()          masks expss::modify()
2018-11-07T15:12:29.128352+00:00 shinyapps[556963]: ✖ purrr::transpose()       masks expss::transpose(), data.table::transpose()
2018-11-07T15:12:29.128347+00:00 shinyapps[556963]: ✖ purrr::modify_if()       masks expss::modify_if()
2018-11-07T15:12:29.128352+00:00 shinyapps[556963]: ✖ lubridate::union()       masks base::union()
2018-11-07T15:12:29.128347+00:00 shinyapps[556963]: ✖ lubridate::month()       masks data.table::month()
2018-11-07T15:12:29.128353+00:00 shinyapps[556963]: ✖ dplyr::vars()            masks ggplot2::vars(), expss::vars()
2018-11-07T15:12:29.128353+00:00 shinyapps[556963]: ✖ lubridate::wday()        masks data.table::wday()
2018-11-07T15:12:29.128353+00:00 shinyapps[556963]: ✖ lubridate::week()        masks data.table::week()
2018-11-07T15:12:29.128354+00:00 shinyapps[556963]: ✖ lubridate::yday()        masks data.table::yday()
2018-11-07T15:12:29.128354+00:00 shinyapps[556963]: ✖ lubridate::year()        masks data.table::year()
2018-11-07T15:12:29.329815+00:00 shinyapps[556963]: 
2018-11-07T15:12:29.329817+00:00 shinyapps[556963]: Listening on http://127.0.0.1:42714
2018-11-07T15:12:39.608656+00:00 shinyapps[556963]: Warning: Error in data.table: object '.R.listCopiesNamed' not found
2018-11-07T15:12:39.615998+00:00 shinyapps[556963]:   135: data.table
2018-11-07T15:12:39.615999+00:00 shinyapps[556963]:   134: elementary_cro_fun_df
2018-11-07T15:12:39.616000+00:00 shinyapps[556963]:   133: FUN
2018-11-07T15:12:39.616000+00:00 shinyapps[556963]:   132: lapply
2018-11-07T15:12:39.616001+00:00 shinyapps[556963]:   131: FUN
2018-11-07T15:12:39.616001+00:00 shinyapps[556963]:   130: lapply
2018-11-07T15:12:39.616002+00:00 shinyapps[556963]:   129: cro_fun
2018-11-07T15:12:39.616002+00:00 shinyapps[556963]:   128: tab_stat_fun_internal
2018-11-07T15:12:39.616003+00:00 shinyapps[556963]:   127: tab_stat_mean_sd_n
2018-11-07T15:12:39.616004+00:00 shinyapps[556963]:   121: freduce
2018-11-07T15:12:39.616003+00:00 shinyapps[556963]:   122: function_list[[i]]
2018-11-07T15:12:39.616004+00:00 shinyapps[556963]:   120: _fseq
2018-11-07T15:12:39.616005+00:00 shinyapps[556963]:   119: eval
2018-11-07T15:12:39.616005+00:00 shinyapps[556963]:   118: eval
2018-11-07T15:12:39.616006+00:00 shinyapps[556963]:   116: %>%
2018-11-07T15:12:39.616007+00:00 shinyapps[556963]:   114: exprFunc [/srv/connect/apps/test/app.R#133]
2018-11-07T15:12:39.616007+00:00 shinyapps[556963]:   113: widgetFunc
2018-11-07T15:12:39.616008+00:00 shinyapps[556963]:   112: func
2018-11-07T15:12:39.616044+00:00 shinyapps[556963]:    99: origRenderFunc
2018-11-07T15:12:39.616045+00:00 shinyapps[556963]:    98: renderFunc
2018-11-07T15:12:39.616046+00:00 shinyapps[556963]:    94: origRenderFunc
2018-11-07T15:12:39.616047+00:00 shinyapps[556963]:    93: output$myBrandTable
2018-11-07T15:12:39.616084+00:00 shinyapps[556963]:    12: fn
2018-11-07T15:12:39.616085+00:00 shinyapps[556963]:     6: eval
2018-11-07T15:12:39.616083+00:00 shinyapps[556963]:    13: runApp
2018-11-07T15:12:39.616085+00:00 shinyapps[556963]:     5: eval
2018-11-07T15:12:39.616084+00:00 shinyapps[556963]:     7: connect$retry
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution: Update R & RStudio software.